# Kalman filters(in simple words)

Tags: control, control-system, kalman-filter

What are Kalman filters and what are their applications? Please give simple explanation. I have tried studying different links but felt hard to digest/understand

Comment: Kalman filter is an optimal state estimator. And it is what it is mainly used for - to estimate/predict the state from measurements.

Comment: @EugeneSh. state ? state of system?

Comment: Of system of course. System is a broad term, it can even be a state of the stock market.

Comment: You might want to browse some on [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) and ask this question there if you don't find it already answered.

Comment: Noisy measurements in, next state (step) estimate comes out.

Comment: Simple words? The Kalman Filter models the mean and the noise of the system and carries it over to the next timestep. There is no easy way to understand kalman filters. There are a few different ways to derive kalman filters depending if your coming from a Bayesian or controls/filters perspective. You don't really get a clear picture of what they do until you understand both

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/kirtley/kirtley/binlustuff/literature/control/Kalman%20filter.pdf

Comment: Start with Weiner optimal filters and phase locked loops (PLL.) Then proceed to Kalman and Kalman-Bucy. I'd recommend also that you get one of the editions of Numerical Recipes to study. An example of a Kalman filter is illustrated by the case of a frequency modulated carrier, where a slowly varying parameter is the instantaneous frequency. In this case, a PLL is a Kalman filter.

Answer (score 6):

I work on systems that incorporate Kalman filters, but I don't design them myself. So here's my "layman's description" of what's going on:

A Kalman filter maintains an internal model of some physical system. You take measurements of that physical system and feed them to the filter to update the model. You can then use data from that model in place of data from the physical system.

The problem is that the measurements (also called "observables") do not necessarily relate directly to the state information you're interested in. Furthermore, the measurements themselves might be corrupted by noise and other errors.

Therefore, the Kalman filter also models how the measurements relate to the true state of the system. It makes those same measurements on its model, and checks to see how well those measurements correlate with the actual measurements. This allows it to assign weighting factors to the measurements based on how "trustworthy" they are, before it uses them to update its internal state. It can also model things like bias and scale factor errors in the data.

In this way, it can be shown that the state of the internal model is the best possible estimate (in a strict mathematical sense) of the true state of the system.

---

In the systems that I work on, we're interested in the best possible estimate of the true position, velocity and orientation of a vehicle. The observables are things like acceleration and rotation rate from an IMU, magnetic field direction from an electronic compass, and satellite range and range rates from one or more GNSS receivers. The outputs of the Kalman filter are position, velocity and attitude of the vehicle.

Comment: I couldn't understand your point at end of 2nd line in 2nd para:"You can then use data from that model in place of data from the physical system''                                        What do you mean here?Do you mean ,we can use data from model to predict future state of system or you mean that we can replace the original  measurement data of physical system  with that of internal model?

Comment: Look at my example. I want to know the attitude of the vehicle, but that isn't something I can measure directly from any of my sensors. But I can get that information directly from the model, because that is part of its internal state.

Answer (score 1):

A Kalman filter is usually just an optimization of one, or a set of simple fixed or weighted estimators, such as linear or low order regression fits, plus optional extrapolation and statistical distribution estimation.

However, when getting a new time sample, instead of re-running the entire regression on the entire previous data set plus the one new sample (potentially zillions of inputs and zillions of arithmetic operations), a Kalman filter simply uses some state information left by a previous time step computation plus the one new sample.  Using one data input, plus a few state inputs, results in vastly fewer math operations to provide an updated fit and/or statistical estimation, compared to re-running entire regressions on long data sets.  Thus also requiring a lot less data storage (computer memory and bandwidth).

What once required a Kalman filter on an ancient 1 MIP VAX to keep up with real-time input, can now be done by brute force (recomputing entire regressions every frame) on a typical mobile phone CPU.  (Thus possibly allowing dynamically optimizing a non-linear estimator.)